# Moving one database in wamp and not the whole directory?

Tags: mysql, database, wamp

Is it possible in wamp to move a single database to another location but not the whole mysql-data directory?

All I can find is that in my.ini you can change "datadir" to another path but as I understand it you have to move all databases to the new location. I have several different databases on my computer using wamp, and most of them I want to have in the original location, but one of them I want to have in another directory (for cloud sharing reasons). Is this possible?

Comment: If you are considering using DropBox or similiar so you can see a database on more than one PC. ITS A BAD IDEA

Comment: @RiggsFolly Do you have any better suggestion if we are two developers and we want to develop locally on our own computers (we don't have access to any server) and we don't want to have to mail the database each time someone makes a change in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is possible to use SYMLINKs or rather JUNCTIONS as they are called in Windows.

[Hard links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you are using WAMPServer 2.5 and you want to see a JUNCTION in action look in the \wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\bin folder, there are a number in there linking to the php folder. If not then just do this to create them

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> click on the version number
```

This will create the links.

So you would move the actual data files out of \wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\data\xxx to a shared locations.

You then create a junction in the \wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\data\xxx folder for each file. MySQl will work having done this. Not sure if these junctions will work if you try to link to a cloud.

**HOWEVER Here be dragons**

The problem with this approach when used with MySQL data files is that you have 2 seperate MYSQL instances, that do not know about each other, both thinking they are in complete control of this database and its tables.

So if a user on MYSQL1 and on MYSQL2 both attempt some process that requires a lock or something like that, they dont know that the other thinks its got a lock, but of course MYSQL1 is only locking other processes going through MYSQL1 so MYSQL2 could be doing exactly the same thing thinking it has locks, but its only locking processes on MYSQL2.

**Data corruption** is only a hop-skip-and-a-jump away using this approach.

As MYSQL is a database SERVER, you should consider installing a MYSQL on your cloud and then any number of people can connect to it and all the functions of a Database Manager will work correctly.

Your web site/Application then connects to this MYSQL Server in the cloud and does not use the MYSQL running on your PC.

On the cloud MYSQL, you just need to setup a userid that your site/app uses and that userid is allowed to connect from 2 remove hosts, i.e. you and you buddies ip addresses, and has the correct privilages just on the database you are both working on.

Of course make sure the root user has a VERY GOOD password on it, and can only be used from you and your buddies ip address.

I hope this gets you moving in the right direction.

Comment: I understand the problem, and decided that we have to copy the database between each other everythime anyone makes a change. The problem is that the cloud we are using (Dropbox) doesn't have a database host.

We chose to use Dropbox because we both use it and my partner doesn't know git (or similar) well enough, and this project os too small (and too limited in time) to have time to learn new software.

For the same reason and that we don't have any economic resources, we can't afford to get an online site host for this project.

Comment: Probably the best solution in the circumstances. I was tempted to suggest GIT but it is definitely not for the faint hearted.